# fnCallback function not able to render Server Side data in DataTable

Tags: datatables

I am not able to render Jquery DataTable with paging at server side.

My DataTable structure is as follows:

---

$("#MyTable").DataTable({

```
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": $("#apiUrl").attr("value") + "/myclass/myMethod",
        "sAjaxDataProp": "",
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bVisible": true,
        "order": [
            [1, "asc"]
        ],
        scrollX: true,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        "oColReorder": {
            "iFixedColumns": 1
        },
            "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ) {
                oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
                    "dataType": 'json',
                    "type": "POST",
                    "url": sSource,
                    "data": aoData,
                    "success": function (msg) {
                        fnCallback(msg.aaData);
                        //$("#members").show();
                    }
                } );
            },
            "columns": [
                    { "data": "Id" },
                    { "data": "VIN" },
                    { "data": "ModelGroupId" },
                    { "data": "Mark" }
            ],
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bVisible": true
    });
```

---

Structure of JSON data from Ajax call is as follows that has three rows of data:

**{"aaData":[{"Id":"1","VIN":"VIN345345354345345","ModelGroupId":"10","Mark":"NDE5234"},{"Id":"2","VIN":"VIN345343445345","ModelGroupId":"10","Mark":"NDE5234"},{"Id":"3","VIN":"VIN345343445345","ModelGroupId":"10","Mark":"NDE5234"}],"sEcho":1,"iTotalRecords":3,"iTotalDisplayRecords":3}**

When I am passing my json data from AJAX success call to fnCallback method, DataTable is showing no result, code is as follows:

```
            "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ) {
                oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
                    "dataType": 'json',
                    "type": "POST",
                    "url": sSource,
                    "data": aoData,
                    "success": function (msg) {
                        fnCallback(msg);
                        //$("#members").show();
                    }
                } );
            }
```

Here the problem is that when I am passing json result to fnCallback function as **fnCallback(msg)**, then DataTable is showing no result. But when I am passing json data to **fnCallback** function as **fnCallback(msg.aaData)** then DataTable is able to render 3 records in the grid, however other information related to paging like Page information from Server is lost as >> **sEcho, iTotalRecords, iTotalDisplayRecords** are part of **msg** and not **msg.aaData** from JSON.

Please, can someone help on this?

Comment: I have solved the issue, I tried different approach:

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue, I tried different approach :

$("#MyTable").DataTable({

```
    "bServerSide": true,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": $("#apiUrl").attr("value") + "/myClass/myMethod",     //to call web API
        "type": "POST",
        "data": function (d) {  //extra parameters to append with Post Data
            d.order_0_column = d.order[0].column;
            d.order_0_dir = d.order[0].dir;
            d.ModelGroup = searchOptionObject.ModelGroup;
            d.RegistrationMark = searchOptionObject.RegistrationMark;
            d.VIN = searchOptionObject.VIN;
            d.StartDate = searchOptionObject.StartDate;
            d.EndDate = searchOptionObject.EndDate;
            d.Source = searchOptionObject.Source;
            d.Status = searchOptionObject.Status;

            for (i = 0; i < d.columns.length; i++)   //binding search parameters to fetch filter data from each column
            {
                d[d.columns[i].data + "_searchValue"] = d.columns[i].search.value
            }
        }
    },
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bVisible": true,
    "order": [
        [1, "asc"]
    ],
    scrollX: true,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    "oColReorder": {
        "iFixedColumns": 1
    },
    "columns": [
                    { "data": "Id" },
                    { "data": "VIN" },
                    { "data": "ModelGroupId" },
                    { "data": "Mark" }
    ],
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bVisible": true,
                "columnDefs": [
                    {
                        "targets": [0],
                        "visible": false,
                        "searchable": true
                    }]

});
```

My API class is as belows:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public parseJsonData SearchOption(SearchOption1 searchOption)
    {
        //write logic to fetch data from data source

        parseJsonData dto = new parseJsonData();
        dto.data = returnList;  // List of records
        dto.draw = draw;  //it should be same that you are getting from Client via Ajax call
        dto.recordsTotal = 24; // total records, should be from datasource
        dto.recordsFiltered = 24;  //filtered records, should be from data source
        return dto;
    }



Model Class:

public class SearchOption1
{
    public int draw { get; set; }
    public int start { get; set; }
    public int length { get; set; }
    public int order_0_column { get; set; }
    public string order_0_dir { get; set; }
    public int ModelGroup { get; set; }
    public string RegistrationMark { get; set; }
    public string VIN { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public int Source { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    //You can add extra Parameters to map from Post data that you are getting from Ajax Call
}

public class parseJsonData
{
    public List<MyDataList> data { get; set; }
    public int draw { get; set; }
    public int recordsTotal { get; set; }
    public int recordsFiltered { get; set; }
}
```

Json structure that is sent to client : {"data":[{"Id":"1","VIN":"VIN345345354345345","ModelGroupId":"10","Mark":"NDE5234"},{"Id":"2","VIN":"VIN345343445345","ModelGroupId":"10","Mark":"NDE5234"},{"Id":"3","VIN":"VIN345343445345","ModelGroupId":"10","Mark":"NDE5234"}],"draw":1,"recordsTotal":24,"recordsFiltered":24}